# How to import theme in shopify?

Tags: shopify

I took backup my Shopify store data using Themes -> Action -> Duplicate option and I'm tried to import this theme into my new Shopify account using Themes -> Theme Library -> Upload theme.

But I can't able to get my old web stores data such as logo, products, Contact Us, About Us and other stuff.

Can any help me to fix that issue?

Here are my store's links

Store 1 : https://aasthaworld-markertplace.myshopify.com

Store 2 : https://kevell-textiles.myshopify.com

Answer (score 0):

The Shopify data is not stored in the theme files

This means that all of the:

- images
- pages
- products
- navigations
- collections
- blogs
- orders
- customers
  etc..

Will NOT be transferred. You need to use an App or to manually transfer all of the content you need.

One of the many "joys" when transferring stores in Shopify.

Answer (score 0):

Go to;

- Online Store
- Import Theme
- Upload theme (under Theme Library)

Once you have activated the theme you will be able to see it on your store.

You will need to do separate exports for products, customers, pages etc. Some may require manual imports, or copy & paste.